# Shared variable in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm new in vhdl (with ISE project navigator) and I'm having a little problem to synthesize this program (sequence.vhd):

```
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

PACKAGE mypack IS
VARIABLE counter: STD_LOGIC := '0' ;
VARIABLE simultaneous : STD_LOGIC := '0' ;
END PACKAGE mypack;

LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


--library work;

USE WORK.mypack.ALL;

ENTITY secuencia IS

PORT(
    polh            : IN    STD_LOGIC; --uno
    polv            : IN    STD_LOGIC; --cero
    seq            : OUT   std_logic_vector(8 downto 0):= (others => 'Z')
);

END secuencia;


ARCHITECTURE registro OF secuencia IS

SIGNAL stack : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0);


BEGIN
PROCESS(polh, polv)
 BEGIN

        IF (polh'event) and (polh='1') and (polv='0')THEN
            stack(counter) <= '1';
            counter := counter +1;

        ELSE IF (polv'event) and (polv='1') and (polh='0')THEN
            stack(counter) <= '0';
            counter := counter +1;
        ELSE IF (polh'event) and (polh='1') and (polv'event) and 
(polv='1') THEN
            simultaneous := simultaneous+1;

        END IF;

END PROCESS;

END registro;
```

And these are the first two errors:

> Line 5.  Only SHARED variables can be declared here.
>
> Line 6.  Only SHARED variables can be declared here.

So the problem is with my declared variables... The purpose is use them in the architecture. I'm sure is a newbie problem but I can't see the solutions. Thx a lot!

PD: I couldn't format properly the code, sorry

---

UPDATE:

Thx for helping @Martin Thompson  . I did what you suggested and now im having a different type or problem. I've been searching about it but it seems to have a broad range of causatives. Here it is the code

```
ENTITY secuencia IS
PORT(
    polh            : IN    STD_LOGIC; --uno
    polv            : IN    STD_LOGIC; --cero
    Pedido      : IN    STD_LOGIC; 
    DatoListo   : OUT    STD_LOGIC; 
    seq            : OUT   std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0):= (others =>   'Z')

);
END secuencia;


ARCHITECTURE registro OF secuencia IS

SIGNAL stack : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0);


BEGIN

PROCESS(polh, polv, Pedido) 

variable counteria : natural;
 variable Listo : integer;
 variable simultaneo : integer;
 BEGIN
    IF (counteria < 1000) THEN

       IF (polh'event AND polh='1' AND polv='0') THEN
        --IF (polh='1' AND polv='0') THEN
            stack(counteria) <= '1';
            counteria := counteria +1;


         ELSIF (polv'event AND polv='1' AND polh='0') THEN
         --ELSIF (polv='1' AND polh='0') THEN    
                stack(counteria) <= '0';
                counteria := counteria +1;                 

        ELSIF (polh'event AND polh='1' AND polv'event AND polv='1') THEN
           simultaneo := simultaneo+1;

END IF;

    ELSIF (counteria = 1000)THEN
      DatoListo <='1';
          IF (Pedido='1')THEN
               Seq  <= stack;            
           counteria := 0;
       DatoListo <='0';
            END IF;                                 
    END IF;

END PROCESS;
END registro;
```

and it gives this error

> line 25: Signal stack> cannot be synthesized, bad
>   synchronous description. The description style you are using to
>   describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not
>   supported in the current software release.

---

UPDATE 2:

I have make some changes and commenting a part of the program, it synthesize:

```
PROCESS(polh, polv, Pedido) 

     variable counteria : natural := 0;
     variable Listo : integer;
     variable simultaneo : integer;
 BEGIN
    IF (counteria < 1000) THEN
       IF rising_edge(polh) THEN
            IF (polv='0') THEN
               stack(counteria) <= '1';     
               counteria := counteria + 1;
            END IF;
--     ELSIF rising_edge(polv)  THEN
--          IF (polh='0') THEN
--             stack(counteria) <= '0';
--             counteria := counteria +1;                  
--          END IF;
--     END IF;

       ELSIF (counteria = 1000)THEN
           DatoListo <='1';
              IF (Pedido='1')THEN
                  Seq   <= stack;            
           counteria := 0;
           DatoListo <='0';
       ENDIF;                                           

    END IF;

END PROCESS;
END registro;
```

This Synthesize. However when I uncomment the `ELSIF rising_edge(polv)  THEN` part, it presents the same problem: `Signal stack<counteria<9:0>> cannot be synthesized...`

Answer (score 5):

Don't use shared variables for now.  You need to understand some basics first.

If you need to "send" the value of `counter` out to somewhere else, add an item to the `port` and write it to there.

If (as it appears) you just want to use it as storage, declare it within the `process` you use it within.

Finally, if you hope to synthesize this, you need to have a clock signal coming in through the `port` and you need to make a standard clocked process:

If you want to find when your polh and polv inputs change, you have to store the previous value and check if it's different to the current value.

```
process (clk)
    variable vpol_last : std_logic;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
       if vpol_last /= vpol then -- it's changed
       -- do something
       end if;
       vpol_last := vpol; -- store current value for next time.
       -- etc.
  end if;
end process;
```